как отключить выделение соответствующих скобок разным цветом visual studio
вопрос в названии темы. пример на скрине (дело не в теме, с ней все хорошо, ее делал я сам):


ее делал я сам - а теперь вы предлагаете по фотографии угадать, что именно вы сделали неправильно?

@aleksandrbarakin В заголовке вроде прямо написано про отключение разноцветных скобок.

В настройках Text Editor -> General -> Display снять галочку Enable brace pair colorization.


спасибо, это помогло!
